# Get records from Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

On Access 2010 I need to use VBA to get the records in a table, process them and put them in a new table. Could you tell me how can I do?

Is there a way similar to C # to put everything into a datatable the result of a query?

I found an example on how to get the data. http://pastebin.com/bCtg20jp

But it always fails on the first statement "ADODB.Recordset". I went to see the included libraries and library that uses ADODB is already included "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library".

Comment: You need to tell vba that you're using the currentDb, assign the record set, open the recordset, perform your code and then write a query or SQL string to insert the records into a new table.

Comment: As suggested above, are you using the current database or external database requiring a connection? Also, are you appending data or creating a new table from query? Couple routes can be taken: 1) Open a recordset via VBA and run an action query to append (INSERT INTO...) to an already existing table; 2) use a Make-Table stored query called by VBA DoCmd.OpenQuery rather than using VBA recordsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you said *'... always fails on the first statement "ADODB.Recordset". I went to see the included libraries and library that uses ADODB is already included "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library"'*, I think you meant this line in the pastebin code ...

```vb
Dim rstEmployees As ADODB.Recordset
```

But ADODB is not provided by the Access Object Library.  You need to include a reference for ActiveX Data Objects.  This screenshot is from Access 2007.  I don't recall which ADODB versions are available in Access 2010.  If in doubt, try the highest version number from the choices Access offers.

[image]

I'm uncertain how many other hurdles you will encounter after this.  One point which confuses me is that your question asks about VBA but your pastebin code is tagged for VB.Net ... as long as you understand the differences between them you may be OK.  Good luck.